# asp.net mvc Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Tables Students and Marks, Each Class have different number of students,

## StudentTable

- StudentId
- StudentName
- Class

## MarksTable

- MarksId
- StudentId
- ExamDate
- MarksScored

I am trying to create a form on which I want to generate *MarksTable* Structure for all student in selected Class, e.g class 9th have 45 students, I want to generate 45 rows 1 for each student, and want a bulk insert into *MarksTable* 1 row for each student.

On This Page we are allowing teacher to select the class and with jquery we are updating the DOM with number of rows, please help

Regards

Comment: Please post the code u have tried

Comment: Is there a question hidden in that specification somewhere? I see no question marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing your data as JSON to the server could be your solution.

Now assuming your web page has a table with 45 rows, and each row has 5 text boxes (say for entering subject marks). You need to walk through all the rows and construct your array of json object (each representing a student).

```
var students = [];
$('#students tbody tr').each(function(indx, el){
    arrtd = $(el).find('td');   
    var student_id = arrtd[0].innerHTML;
    var student_name = arrtd[1].innerHTML;
    var subject_1 = arrtd[2].innerHTML;
    //...
    students.append(
        {
            studentid: student_id,
            name: student_name,
            ...
        }
    );
});

var stringify_result = JSON.stringify(students);
```

This stringified version becomes an argument to the corresponding action on the server. You can either assign its value to a hidden variable and submit the form on the server; or pass it as arguments in a `$.ajax` call.

On the server side you need to use newtonsoft json library to parse the json string:

```
public ActionResult BulkInsert(string students_json)
{
    var jarr = JArray.Parse(students_json);
    foreach(JObject obj in jarr)
    {
        var student_id = obj['studentid'].Value;
        //...
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try file upload functionality for bulk insert at once.